# What gives the context to ngTemplate in case of *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor, angular2-directives, ng-template

I had some confusion regarding `ngTemplateOutletContext` , specifically how it is passed to `ngTemplate` or who passes it to `ngTemplate` which surrounds the element on which `*ngFor` was applied. The confusion builds up when I compare it to the way, when we explicitly pass which `ngTemplate` to render.

Here is what I think happens when we explicitly pass the template -

Say we have an `ngContainer` / `ngTemplate` / `( Literally any HTML element as ngTemplateOutlet & ngTemplateOutletContext can be applied to any element)`, Now we chose to explicitly provide a template which we have created earlier. Like this -

```
<ng-template #temp let-number>
  <p>{{number}}</p>
</ng-template>
```

And we pass it to some element on which we have applied `ngTemplateOutlet` and `ngTemplateOutletContext` like this -

```
<div [ngTemplateOutlet]="temp" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: 4}">
</div>
```

(We should have used `ng-container` for the above operation as it won't be in the DOM, but it doesn't concern me here.)

Now the `temp` `ngTemplate` will be there having context as what was passed by the `div` ( or any other parent container ) like this -

[image]

What I understand here is we stamp out the `ng-template` provided in the `ngTemplateOutlet` having context passed in `ngTemplateOutletContext`. We create local variables to use in the template itself.

---

**THE PROBLEM**

---

When we are using `*ngFor` like -

```
<p *ngFor="let number of data">
  {{number}}
</p>
```

and it de-sugars it the following way -

```
<ng-template #temp ngFor [ngForOf]="data" let-number>
  <p>{{number}}</p>
</ng-template>
```

where `data` variable in `ts` file is `data = [1,2,3]`

`The question is` -

***1.)*** Who provides the values ( context ) to this de-sugared `ng-template` so that it is able to bind let-number to the $implicit properties. I looked into [ngForOfContext](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOfContext) , there I found that some variable are provided that's why we are able bind variable like `even`, `index` like -

```
<p *ngFor="let number of data; let i=index; let isEven=even">
```

but who provides these variables in this case to the `ng-template`. ( When we explicitly pass template, the parent container (`div` here) provided the context as we saw earlier )

***2.)*** When we set `ngForTemplate` it expects a template of type `TemplateRef` as given here-

[image]

Using `p` with the *ngFor Directive allows it, but setting a reference of `p` explicitly when using de-sugared version of `ngFor` disallows it i.e. -

```
<ng-template #temp ngFor [ngForOf]="data" [ngForTemplate]="pTemplate" let-number>
```

where `pTemplate` is -

```
<p #pTemplate *ngFor="let number of data; let i=index; let isEven=even">
  {{number}} {{i}} {{isEven}}
</p>
```

but it doesn't recognise `ptemplate` in `ngForTemplate` . If it doesn't recognise `pTemplate` as a valid `ngForTemplate`, how is it able to stamp out `p`'s in `*ngFor` version of it ?

PS: If I am incorrect in my understanding of `ng-template` before the questions , I will be more than happy to correct that as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we use the ngFor directive like :

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let number of data;let i = index;let isEven=even">
    <p [class.even]="isEven">{{i}} : {{number}}</p>
</ng-container>
```

The inner html is an ng-template. The ngFor directive provides the context to this template for each iteration of the loop.

As you noted there's a ngForTemplate input on the ngFor directive. We can use it to set a template declared outside of the ngFor inner Html

```html
<ng-template #pTemplate let-number let-isEven="even" let-i="index">
    <p [class.even]="isEven">{{i}} : {{number}}</p>
</ng-template>


<ng-container *ngFor="let number of data;let i = index;let isEven=even;template: pTemplate">
</ng-container>
```

So the ngFor directive provides the context to this template. This context has the type `ngForOfContext`

We can use this template with an ngTemplateOutlet by providing the context ourself :

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="pTemplate;context:{$implicit:43,even:true,index:2}">
</ng-container>
```

But the *ngFor syntax is a syntaxic sugar for an ngTemplate. We can use it without the sugar like this :

```html
<ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="data"  let-number let-isEven="even" let-i="index">
    <p [class.even]="isEven">{{i}} : {{number}}</p>
</ng-template>
```

Here the ng-template is still the template applied for each iteration. We can also use it in a ngTemplateOutlet by providing a context :

```html
<ng-template #templ ngFor [ngForOf]="data"  let-number let-isEven="even" let-i="index">
    <p [class.even]="isEven">{{i}} : {{number}}</p>
</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="templ;context:{$implicit:43,even:true,index:2}">
</ng-container>
```

But if use the de-sugared syntax with the `ngForTemplate` input we have to declare a 2nd ng-template element. Because if we try to apply the ngFor directive without the * on anything else than an ng-template we get an error.

If we look at the [source code of the ngFor directive](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts#L186) We can see that it requires a templateRef in it's constructor. But the value of this template ref is also set by the ngForTemplate input.

So we need to write

```html
<ng-template #pTemplate let-number let-isEven="even" let-i="index">
    <p [class.even]="isEven">{{i}} : {{number}}</p>
</ng-template>

<ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="data" [ngForTemplate]="pTemplate"></ng-template>

<!-- And we cannot write : -->
<ng-container ngFor [ngForOf]="data" [ngForTemplate]="pTemplate"></ng-container>
```

In this case we have 2 templates, but only one is used and so the template on which we put the ngFor doesn't need a context, its only purpose it to be able to call the ngFor directive.

Hope this answers your questions.